# Deferred rendering position recontruct

Tags: opengl, glsl, lwjgl, deferred-rendering

I made the first step of deferred rendering, the FBO with color, normal, position and depth texture. But when I do the lighting the positions are moving and rotating with me.

First pass vertex:

```
void main(){
    gl_Position=gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix*gl_Vertex;
    vec4 positiontotexture = gl_ModelViewProjectionMartix*gl_Vertex;
}
```

So how can I get the original position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that `positiontotexture` will go to the fragment shader and then be saved in the texture.

When doing first pass it would be good to have View position, not ViewProjection. You can use:

```
vec4 positiontotexture = gl_ModelViewMartix*gl_Vertex;
```

in the second pass you can then use:

```
vec3 position = texture(texPos, vVaryingTexCoord0.xy).rgb;
```

The previous way is quite simple (yet it is good when learning) but require lot of memory (you have to store 3 element vector).
Better way is to recreate view-position from screen position/depth: [link to article](http://mynameismjp.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/reconstructing-position-from-depth/). 
Such techniques are used in modern engines. (Thanks [andon-m-coleman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423205/andon-m-coleman) for the suggestion)

Here is my repo with some basic deferred: https://github.com/fenbf/efg_deferred/tree/master/code/shaders

Comment: @Csoki: Definitely prefer the second technique, an extra G-Buffer with adequate precision to store the view/world space position is going to absolutely destroy your memory bandwidth requirements. No commercial graphics engine uses this approach, they all reconstruct the position from the depth buffer and projection matrix.